# How can I set remote drive quota using script or command

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

We have a Windows 10 administration console to mount all shares.
The administration console is joined to an AD domain.
We are using the file explorer in the admin. console to set user disk quota.
Before setting a user disk quota, waiting to load all quota entries takes a long time.
So, is there any script or command line that can do the job?

Unfortunately, the fsutil utility is for local volume only.

Comment: Powershell FTW! If you need guidance let me know then I create a answer

Comment: Yes, I want to have a guidance/tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Check if Fsrm module is installed
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Fsrm)) {
    Write-Host "File Server Resource Manager module not installed. Please install it and run the script again."
    return
}
 # Import the File Server Resource Manager module
    Import-Module Fsrm
    
    # Specify the username and path to the folder you want to set quotas for
    $username = "JohnDoe"
    $folderPath = "C:\Users\$username\Documents"
    
    # Set the quota limit (in bytes)
    $quotaLimit = 500MB
    
    # Create a new quota
    New-FsrmQuota -Path $folderPath -UserName $username -Size $quotaLimit -Enforce
    
    # Optionally, you can set an email notification for the user
    Set-FsrmQuota -Path $folderPath -UserName $username -Notification $true -NotificationLimit $quotaLimit
```

If you use quota templates you can just assign the template with PowerShell

```
# Import the File Server Resource Manager module
Import-Module Fsrm

# Specify the username and path to the folder you want to set quotas for
$username = "JohnDoe"
$folderPath = "C:\Users\$username\Documents"

# Specify the name of the quota template
$quotaTemplateName = "StandardTemplate"

# Assign the quota template to the folder
Set-FsrmQuota -Path $folderPath -UserName $username -TemplateName $quotaTemplateName
```

I assumed you use fsrm for quota. You can't do this for a remote drive, this needs to be done on fileserver hosting the data.

Comment: Do I need to install the fsrm on my admin. console.?

Comment: If you don't have the powershell module then yes, but it might got installed when you installed the fsrm Admin tools. I will update my script to check if it's installed

Comment: How can I install the fsrm Admin. tools?

Comment: Usually it's installed with the role so it could be present on your file servers,or servers having the file services role. Otherwise you can install it using PowerShell `Install-WindowsFeature -Name FS-Resource-Manager`. Again quotas need to be set on the file servers itself